# Conditionally hide scrollbar in svelte

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, svelte

It is kinda easy. I replaced the normal scrollbar with a custom one and want to hide it only when I'm not actively scrolling. I was so thinking about conditional CSS but can't succeed to anything.

The issue is mostly since I use svelte and not sveltekit to apply to the whole body I use the ":global(body)" things. It seems to make my whole kinda strange.

Also I have an animation with shapes on the background that need to be still there. Most of my attempts have broke it sadly.

Would any of you have an idea ?

Here is my code :

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import { fade } from "svelte/transition";
  import Header from "../components/header.svelte"
  import CenterBlock from "../components/centerBlock.svelte";
  import { linear } from "svelte/easing";

  let animate = false

  let shapes = 
  [
    { top: 50, left: 50, deltaX: -1, deltaY: 1 },
    { top: 350, left: 1000, deltaX: -1, deltaY: 1 },
    { top: 200, left: 500, deltaX: -1, deltaY: 1 },
    { top: 650, left: 1100, deltaX: -1, deltaY: 1 },
  ];

  function updateShapes() 
  {
    shapes = shapes.map(shape => 
    {
      let newTop = shape.top + shape.deltaY;
      let newLeft = shape.left + shape.deltaX;
      let shapeRadius = 300; // taille des shapes

      if (newTop <= 0 || newTop  >= window.innerHeight - shapeRadius) 
      {
        shape.deltaY = -shape.deltaY;
      }

      if (newLeft <= 0 || newLeft >= window.innerWidth - shapeRadius) 
      {
        shape.deltaX = -shape.deltaX;
      }

      let updatedShape = 
      {
        top: shape.top + shape.deltaY,
        left: shape.left + shape.deltaX,
        deltaX: shape.deltaX,
        deltaY: shape.deltaY,
      };

      return updatedShape;
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(updateShapes);
  }

  onMount(() => 
  {
    updateShapes();
    animate = true
  });

</script>

{#if animate}
  <div transition:fade={{delay: 250, duration: 1000, easing: linear}}>
    <Header/>
  </div>

  <div id="background" transition:fade={{delay:500, duration:5000, easing: linear}}>
    {#each shapes as shape (shape)}
    <div class="shape" style={`top: ${shape.top}px; left: ${shape.left}px;`}></div>
    {/each}
  </div>

  <CenterBlock/>

  <div style="height: 200vh;"></div>
{/if}
  



<style>
  @import '../css/gambetta.css';
  :global(body) 
  {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #151813;
  }

  #background 
  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .shape 
  {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #730d23 40%, transparent 75%);
    filter: blur(30px);
  }

  /* width */
  :root::-webkit-scrollbar 
  {
  width: 10px;
  }

  /* Track */
  :root::-webkit-scrollbar-track 
  {
  background: #151813;
  border-radius: 5px;
  }

  /* Handle */
  :root::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
  {
  background: #730d23;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }

  /* Handle on hover */
  :root::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover 
  {
  background: #400a15;
  }
</style>
```